# Angular: Directive: How to pass require form AND controller to link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

I have a **directive** called *formNavHandler* to handle dirty checking and navigation from page to page. *formNavHandler* relies on a **controller** called *CoolFormCtrl* and a **form** called *coolForm*. I want to pass both *CoolFormCtrl* and *coolForm* to the link function of *formNavHandler*

```
angular.module('cool').directive('formNavHandler', [
  '$log', function($log) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        disabled: '=coolFormDisabled'
      },
      controller: 'CoolFormCtrl',
      require: 'form',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs, WhatsThis) {
        $log.log(WhatsThis);
        ...
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

used like so:

```
<form name="coolForm" form-nav-handler=true cool-form disabled="!CurrentUser.canUpdate">
  ...
</form>
```

My issue is that I cannot figure out how to pass both *form* and *CoolFormCtrl* through the link function.

If I comment out the *require:'form'* line then **WhatsThis = CoolFormCtrl**:

With the *require:'form'* line uncommented **WhatsThis = coolForm**

And when trying to pass a 5th parameter **WhatsThis = coolForm** and **AndThis = undefined**

```
controller: 'CoolFormCtrl',
require: 'form',
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, WhatsThis, AndThis) {
  $log.log(WhatsThis);
  $log.log(AndThis);
```

Is there any way to pass both a controller and required form to a directives link function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
angular.module('cool').directive('formNavHandler', [
   '$log', function($log) {
       return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
             disabled: '=coolFormDisabled'
          },
          require: ['formNavHandler', 'form'],
          controller: 'CoolFormCtrl',
          link: function(scope, elem, attrs, WhatsThis) {
             $log.log(WhatsThis);
             ...
          }
    };
 }]);
```

WhatsThis will be an array of controllers.

Comment: And then inject CoolFormCtrl into my directive? Or declare ng-controller="CoolFormCtrl" on the same form element? this cannot be done if it already has a form Controller